# FTP - Batch file hangs on put / Creates zero bytes file

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I have created a bat file that uses ftp to put a file on another location (code below). If I log on to the location manually I can place the file without a problem.

However, when running the batch file the process hangs at the put command. It does indeed place a file there but it is zero bytes and it never increases.

Any help with this problem would be much appreciated.

```
ftp -s:%0
goto done
open ftp.domain.co.uk
Username
password
cd NewFolder    
put C:\Test.txt
bye
: done
@echo off
exit
```

Comment: you provided insufficient data `:/` - just ask the administrator of the domain `ftp.domain.co.uk`.

Comment: Try removing the c:\ from the put command.  use `lcd` to change local directory.

Comment: @foxidrive Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it with no luck, I'm afraid. It still hangs at '150 Data connection'.

Comment: I think you'll find that the ftp.exe uses passive mode FTP transfers like a web browser, and your server needs active mode.  You might like to investigate that and see if you can download a different command line FTP tool.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue for months. Finally stumbled across the solution today. There are two ftp.exe applications on a 64-bit program (System32 and SysWOW64). Only the System32 version was being allowed through my Windows Defender firewall. I added the other one, and it now works perfectly!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).